# NLP sentiment analysis in Norwegian

Tags: python, natural-language-processing

Please keep in mind that I am very new to data science and completely new to NLP! I am trying to create a model to classify customer reviews as either negative or positive. However, my main problem is that most of them are in Norwegian, which seems not to be very well supported. I have found this repo https://github.com/ltgoslo/norsentlex/tree/master/Fullform containing both negative and positive lexicons and have decided to use it.

```
with open("Fullform_Positive_lexicon.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    positive_lexicon = []
    for row in reader:
        print(str(row))
        positive_lexicon.append(row[0])

with open("Fullform_Negative_lexicon.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    negative_lexicon = []
    for row in reader:
        negative_lexicon.append(row[0])

#adjusted to use it with NaiveBayesClassifier
def get_tokens_for_model(cleaned_tokens_list):
    final_token_list = [] 
    for token in cleaned_tokens_list:
        token_dict = {}
        token_dict.update({token : True})
        final_token_list.append(token_dict)
    return final_token_list

positive_tokens_for_model = get_tokens_for_model(positive_lexicon)
negative_tokens_for_model = get_tokens_for_model(negative_lexicon)

positive_dataset = [(token, "Positive")
                     for token in positive_tokens_for_model]

negative_dataset = [(token, "Negative")
                     for token in negative_tokens_for_model]

dataset = positive_dataset + negative_dataset
#shuffle dataset
for i in range(len(dataset)-1, 0, -1): 
    j = random.randint(0, i + 1)  
    dataset[i], dataset[j] = dataset[j], dataset[i]  

train_data = dataset[:20000]
test_data = dataset[7742:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)

print("Accuracy is:", classify.accuracy(classifier, test_data))
```

So I am just training my model based on this lexicon and then I am trying to apply it to my comments. I am getting here 87%, which is not so bad. However, it looks worse when used with whole sentences.

```
with open("stopwords.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    norwegian_stopwords = []
    for row in reader:
        norwegian_stopwords.append(row[0])

customer_feedback = pd.read_excel("classification_sample.xlsx")
customer_feedback = customer_feedback.dropna()
customer_feedback['Kommentar'] = customer_feedback['Kommentar'].apply(remove_punctuation)

list_of_comments = list(customer_feedback['Kommentar'])

for comment in list_of_comments:
    custom_tokens = word_tokenize(comment)
    filtered_tokens = []
    for word in custom_tokens:
        if word not in  norwegian_stopwords:
            filtered_tokens.append(word)

    classification = classifier.classify(dict([token, True] for token in filtered_tokens))
    probdist = classifier.prob_classify(dict([token, True] for token in filtered_tokens))
    pred_sentiment = probdist.max()
    print("Sentence: " + comment)
    print("Classified as: " + str(classification))
    print("Key words: " + str(custom_tokens))
    print("Probability: " + str(round(probdist.prob(pred_sentiment), 2)))
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
```

I know my code is not the highest quality right now(although suggestions regarding this are also appreciated). I am looking mostly for some feedback what more can I do to improve my accuracy. What is currently not very clear to me, is how to properly train the model on words and then achieve the very same accuracy on sentences.

Comment: Hi, I have forgot to copy this piece of code. Its already there:)

Comment: Where is `word_tokenize` from? Is it from `nltk`? Please include your imports.

Comment: You would benefit from running your tokens through a lemmatizer or a stemmer. If the word "glad" is in your positive tokens list, you'll want to find "glade" and "gladere" too.

Comment: @Łukasz D. Tulikowski: have a word about suggested edit in [CR chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101063/suggested-edit-to-cr-q-232373)?

Answer (score 3):

All of this:

```
def get_tokens_for_model(cleaned_tokens_list):
    final_token_list = [] 
    for token in cleaned_tokens_list:
        token_dict = {}
        token_dict.update({token : True})
        final_token_list.append(token_dict)
    return final_token_list

positive_tokens_for_model = get_tokens_for_model(positive_lexicon)
negative_tokens_for_model = get_tokens_for_model(negative_lexicon)

positive_dataset = [(token, "Positive")
                     for token in positive_tokens_for_model]

negative_dataset = [(token, "Negative")
                     for token in negative_tokens_for_model]

dataset = positive_dataset + negative_dataset
#shuffle dataset
for i in range(len(dataset)-1, 0, -1): 
    j = random.randint(0, i + 1)  
    dataset[i], dataset[j] = dataset[j], dataset[i]
```

Is just a very verbose way to write:

```
dataset = [({token : True}, "Positive") for token in positive_lexicon]
dataset.extend([({token : True}, "Negative") for token in negative_lexicon])
random.shuffle(dataset)
```

<s>The shuffling probabilities might be a bit different, though. `random.shuffle` basically has for each element equal probability to end up at any index. I think your method has a bias, but I'm not quite sure.</s>

At least your custom shuffling seems to be unbiased:

[image]

However, I had to fix it to this, because otherwise it raises an `IndexError`, because `random.randint` is inclusive of the end (in contrast to `range`, slices and `random.randrange`):

```
#shuffle dataset
for i in range(len(dataset)-1, 0, -1): 
    j = random.randint(0, i)  
    dataset[i], dataset[j] = dataset[j], dataset[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

**#### Ways to significantly improve performance and processing flow:**

*Accumulating lexicon dataset* phase

The first 2 **`for`** loops for accumulating `positive_lexicon` and `negative_lexicon` could at least be optimized with a list comprehension:

```
...
reader = csv.reader(f)
positive_lexicon = [row[0] for row in reader]
```

that's better, but not the best when reading large files. (we'll beat that in the *final* version below)

The next 4 **`for`** loops are redundantly traversing the same sequences for just enriching each entry/token with `{token : True}`, then - with respective keyword flag `"Positive"/"Negative"`.

Since all intermediate datasets are not used anywhere further and just intended to compose a combined final dataset `dataset = positive_dataset + negative_dataset` - all those **6** `for` loops can be substituted with a **single** efficient *generator* function which will be consumed just once and return the needed entries.
The final version for the 1st processing phase (lexicons/accuracy):

```
pos_lexicon_fname = "Fullform_Positive_lexicon.txt"
neg_lexicon_fname = "Fullform_Negative_lexicon.txt"

def get_lexicon_dataset(pos_lexicon_fname, neg_lexicon_fname):
    with open(pos_lexicon_fname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield ({row[0]: True}, "Positive")

    with open(neg_lexicon_fname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield ({row[0]: True}, "Negative")

dataset = list(get_lexicon_dataset(pos_lexicon_fname, neg_lexicon_fname))
#shuffle dataset
...
```

---

*Stopwords/tokenizing/probability* phase:

**`norwegian_stopwords`** accumulation approach is better composed with a list comprehension:

```
with open("stopwords.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    norwegian_stopwords = [row[0] row in reader]
```

The code fragment which runs on each iteration (of the outer `for` loop):

```
...
filtered_tokens = []
for word in custom_tokens:
    if word not in  norwegian_stopwords:
        filtered_tokens.append(word)

classification = classifier.classify(dict([token, True] for token in filtered_tokens))
probdist = classifier.prob_classify(dict([token, True] for token in filtered_tokens))
```

introduces 2 issues:

- `filtered_tokens` is better accumulated with a list comprehension
- the same `filtered_tokens` sequence is then redundantly traversed twice

But, considering that the *target* data structure for *classifying* operation is a dictionary of filtered tokens (`dict([token, True], ...)`) - the more optimized and straightforward way is to compose such a dictionary at once:

```
for comment in list_of_comments:
    custom_tokens = word_tokenize(comment)
    filtered_tokens_dict = {word: True for word in custom_tokens
                            if word not in norwegian_stopwords}

    classification = classifier.classify(filtered_tokens_dict)
    probdist = classifier.prob_classify(filtered_tokens_dict)
    pred_sentiment = probdist.max()
    print("Sentence: " + comment)
    ...
```

---

*Things to remember:*

- *Generator expressions* don’t materialize the whole output sequence when they’re run. Instead, generator expressions evaluate to an iterator that yields one item at a time from the expression
- *Generators* can produce a sequence of outputs for arbitrarily large inputs because their working memory doesn’t include all inputs and outputs